# The Upgrade From PHP5 to PHP7 "Broke" Retrieving Array Values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Under PHP5 I was able to use an array (`$_SESSION['issuenum_index']`) developed with the code below.

```
if ($_SESSION['mfilter'] == 0) {
    $query = "SELECT IssueIDNUM,MagazineNUM FROM tblIssueList ORDER by IssueDate DESC, IssueIDNUM ";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT IssueIDNUM,MagazineNUM FROM tblIssueList WHERE MagazineNUM = {$_SESSION['mfilter']} ORDER BY IssueDate DESC, IssueIDNUM ";
}           

$_SESSION['issuenum_index'] =$conn->query($query);

if (!$_SESSION['issuenum_index']) die($conn->error);

$_SESSION['rowcount'] = mysqli_num_rows($_SESSION['issuenum_index']);
```

Now that I have upgraded to PHP7, the array does not seem to work. The correct row count is returned, but the values for `IssueIDNUM` and `MagazineNUM` appear missing.

When I run the code below:

```
    foreach($_SESSION['issuenum_index'] as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key." Value:  ". $value ."<br>" ;
    }
```

I get the result: `"2181 Value: Array"`. The number "2181" is the line number. Instead of the word "Array", I was expecting the values releated to "`IssueIDNUM`" and "`MagazineNUM`".

When I run the following code: `print_r($_SESSION['issuenum_index']);` I get: `"mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 2187 [type] => 0 )"`. I don't see the two field names.

How can the field names be displayed for this array? 
Also how can this code be fixed for PHP7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return of your `$conn->query($query)`is not an array, but mysql_result object which implements Traversable interface, so you can loop through it. `[current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 2187 [type] => 0` are properties of this object. http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php.

So, while we iterating through this object it will return an array of data.
"2181 Value: Array" - 2181 - is the key of your data array. I hope, you've got "218**0** Value: Array" above and so on till 0. Array is where your data is. Just try to print_r($value) and you will see, what is going on.

You could use fetch_all method (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to set all the data inside you session (not asking, why are you doing so)

```
$_SESSION['issuenum_index'] = $conn->query($query)->fetch_all();
```

EDIT: Suggest that your previous PHP version was lower then 5.4, where Traversable interface was added. No deal with PHP7.

Comment: Sounds good. Points to a solution. I'll have to experiment with it. The purpose of this array is to keep track of the cursor location. I am using Ubuntu, which has a tendency, at times, to retain using older versions of a program such as PHP. I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 which allows using PHP7.

Comment: It mostly about of your way to get the data. Usually we use fetch_all, fetch_assoc, fetch_object etc to get the data we need in format we need. It will work on any version of PHP 5 and PHP 7. A lot of examples on manual and on SO, so I'm sure I will find what you need soon

Comment: I've had partial success. I can get a data dump now, so I can see the data. I did not get "$_SESSION['issuenum_index'] = $conn->query($query)->fetch_all();" to work. It may not be significant. It raises the issue of even needing an array versus using the  "mysql_result object". Since I can now parse the "mysql_result object " thanks to your advice, I can retrieve the data. That means that I need to examine some downstream code to revise array dependent code. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Yeah, it may cause a lot of changes to your code as `$conn->query($query)` was working for you. There're some point to read: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php. Just don't be afraid and try it.

Comment: Success, maybe. I changed the code below to the "MYSQLI_NUM" option: while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($_SESSION['issuenum_index'], MYSQLI_NUM)). I can scroll the data set now. As you pointed out, I have "mysql_result object" which is not an associative array. Identifying by column number overcame that. Thanks. (can't get rid of the &#39).

Comment: Glad to help you. Cheers!